# PRISM WPF and MaterialDesignInXaml transitioner

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to use the [Transitioner from MaterialDesignInXaml](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Transitions/Transitioner.cs) with a PRISM 7 WPF app as a region to get animation on navigation. The two "work" together in the sense that navigation of views is succcessful but only the first view animates. After poking around I created my own RegionAdapter with a new RegionBehavior that I copied from [PRISM](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2ecbf13ed59b288d8d88446b535780bdc211b6e1/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/Behaviors/SelectorItemsSourceSyncBehavior.cs) to play around.

I got an idea that maybe the synchronization event handlers were firing before the transitioner had a chance to make its containers that enable its animation. The suspect behavior I noticed was that when [this line executed](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2ecbf13ed59b288d8d88446b535780bdc211b6e1/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/Behaviors/SelectorItemsSourceSyncBehavior.cs#L129) it would clear the SelectedItem of the Transitioner and the animation would not fire. (This was last Friday at end of day so I am sorry it is a little fuzzy on a Monday morning.)

So I added a real sophisticated mechanism to allow the transitioner to "catch up" (`await Task.Delay(1)`) at the [equivalent of this line](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2ecbf13ed59b288d8d88446b535780bdc211b6e1/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/Behaviors/SelectorItemsSourceSyncBehavior.cs#L122) and animation started working. Now it doesn't clear the SelectedItem when the view is deactivated.

My question is why and how can I do it more elegantly? I don't have a ton of experience with custom WPF UI Controls. I don't really like what I have which is basically a forked SelectorRegionAdapter with a race condition waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up digging into the MaterialDesignInXaml codebase and found that the Transitioner does not trigger animations unless the view is loaded. So I ended up replacing my `Task.Delay(1)` with an event handler for the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event.

So I ended up using 90% of the library's SelectorRegionAdapter except where it selects new active views I listen for Loaded and then once that occurs I select the new view.